# Match Image Height To Text Height In CSS Grid Columns

Tags: html, css

Update **I don't want to use display flex**

How do i match the height of the image, on desktops with the height of the title? On mobiles, the full image height is ok but on desktops, the image in the right column is much taller than the title text as seen in this image.

[image]

I'm using CSS grid-template-areas with 2 columns on desktop and 1 on mobiles.

```css
.hero-title-image {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    'hero-title hero-image';
}
    
.hero-title-container {
    grid-area: hero-title;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.wp-hero-image {
    grid-area: hero-mage;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {  
   
    .hero-title-image {
        display: grid;
        grid-row-gap: 30px;
        grid-template-areas:
        'hero-title' 
        'hero-image';
    }
    
    .hero-title-container {
        grid-area: hero-title;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="hero-title-image"><div class="hero-title-container">We help business owners in growth mode break through to the next level.</div><img src="https://i.ibb.co/2359H9t/woman.jpg" class="wp-hero-mage" />
</div>
```

I don't want to use display: flex;. I'm using display: grid;

Comment: added another duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif Are you sure that this is a duplicate? I don't think so because the image has a "growing" width with aspect ratio. All marked duplicates are text-only examples.

Comment: My minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/4uv0edaq/2/